# VBA Outlook - Get email addresses from attached .msg files

Tags: email, vba, outlook

I would like to have some code that helps me to get the email address of the sender of an attached .msg file.

I have an email with around 10 emails attached. I need to copy the sender address from them into the clipboard or an excel sheet.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to

1. save the attachment as an `msg` file,
2. open it using `Namespace.OpenSharedItem`
3. once you open it as `MailItem`, you can read the `MailItem.Sender` properties.

You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it allows to directly open the message attachments as `RDOMail` objects using [RDOAttachment.EmbeddedMsg](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).

Comment: can you please make a simple subrutine with those code? I am not sure how to use them.